# Is there any way to add LTE/WCDMA/GSM (Auto) option in a rooted non LTE device (Note3 Neo)?

Tags: root-access, samsung, hardware, 4g

So my phone is an Indian Note 3 Neo (SM-N750) which has an Exynos processor.
I need to activate the above requested option so as to trick a LTE only sim into believing that my device can support LTE so that it can at least provide me 3G speeds.

Just for clarification, MediaTek and Qualcomm based users can do this using engineer mode tools and services and I know about that. I just want to know is it possible on an Exynos device or not.

As recommended by [Gokul NC](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/112458/gokul-nc) I've tried dialing `*#*#4636#*#*` (and also tried the [4636](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kei5rio.secretcode) app), but with the former nothing happens, and with the latter only the screen flashes shortly and immediately returns to the main screen – so this feature (as outlined in [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDN9Oj_emU8)) seems to be removed from my device.

Comment: You can try *LTE/WCDMA* using Gravity Box Xposed module meaning 4G/3G

Comment: @beeshyams gravity box doesn't works on Touchwiz based Roms afaik. We have wanam xposed and i have that , but it doesn't have any settings related to LTE/WCDMA.

Comment: Gravity Box didn't work fully well. I used it on KitKat on stock TouchWiz . This is one of the things I could activate. I am only sightseeing to try. I don't have stock TW anymore to experiment and confirm

Comment: @XavierJacob That's unfortunate – as it most likely means this feature was removed from this ROM altogether.